# iterating through dictionary with values in the form of lists

Tags: python

When i run the following code, i get an error saying "need more than 1 value to unpack" . Can anyone please tell me how to iterate through this dictionary in order to run the following code

```
globalViewDict = {'A': [('B', 6.5, 5001), ('F', 2.2, 5005), 'A', '2'], 
                  'B': [('A', 6.5, 5000), ('C', 1.1, 5002), ('D', 4.2, 5003), ('E', 3.2, 5004), 'B', '4']}

def dijkstrawPhase():
    global globalViewDict
    tempList =[]
    temptup = ()
    i=0
    x=0
    value = []
    for key,value in globalViewDict:
        neighborsOfPacket = int(value[-1])
        while x < neighborsOfPacket:
            id = str(value[i+0])
            cost = float(value[i+2:i+5])
            temptup =(key,id,cost)        
            i = i + 11
            x = x + 1
            tempList.append(temptup)
    print "tempList",tempList

dijkstrawPhase()
```

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
for key,value in globalViewDict:
```

expects *two* values for each iteration, but iteration over a dictionary only gives you *single* objects, the keys. This is why you get your error.

You probably want to use [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

```
for key,value in globalViewDict.items():
```

`dict.items()` lets you iterate over the `(key, value)` pairs in the dictionary. If you are using Python 2, you may want to use [`dict.iteritems()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) instead to avoid having to create a whole list first.

Comment: OP is using Python 2, I'd add a comment about `items` vs `iteritems`.

Comment: yup! Thank you! :D and happy new year

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo: right, these days I default to Python 3, thanks for pointing that out.